# Changing the names of paired files to random names

Tags: python, filenames

I stuck. 
I have a folder with files with names:

```
individual_1_side1.jpg
individual_1_side2.jpg
individual_98_side1.jpg
individual_98_side2.jpg
```

These are two photos of one individual, so files with the same number ending on _side1.jpg and _side2.jpg are paired. However, I need to change the numbers to other, randomly assigned to an individual. I know only the simplest things in Python... I have tried something like this:

```
import os
import glob
import random

list_of_filenames = []
for element in list_of_filenames:
     parts_of_filename = element.split("_")
     unspecific_name = parts_of_filename[0]
     individual_number = parts_of_filename[1]
     type_of_photo = parts_of_filename[2]
```

I think here I should pair this files somehow by their individual_number, but I don't know how to even start doing it.
I thought the new name should look like this:

```
new_name = str(unspecific_name) + random.sample(xrange(120),1) + str(type_of_photo)
```

And I know that I can use os.rename to rename the files (os.rename(element, new_name)). How should I deal with my paired files? Maybe I am on the wrong path and should change the entire concept?

EDIT: Small edit to answer the comments. I've checked how to change the filenames to random filenames, however, I cannot lose the track of two photos of the same individual. I need to change the names because their current names remind about a history of the research (so the individual 1 was historically first, and the photos grouped together) and I have to give them names without that associations.

THANK YOU, you're awesome :)

Comment: Could you post your desired output?

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, it's hard to tell whether you're on the right track when we don't know what you're trying to achieve by renaming the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's try something like:

```
import os, random
individuals = set() # keep only unique individuals
for filename in os.listdir('/path/to/folder'):
    individuals.add( int(filename.split('_')[1]) ) # get the integer "individual number"

individuals = list(individuals) # cast to list type
random.shuffle(individuals)  # random shuffle
# move the files
for i, id in enumerate(individuals):
    for side in [1,2]:
        orig_name = 'individual_{}_side{}.jpg'.format(id, side)
        new_name = 'randid_{}_side{}.jpg'.format(i, side)
        os.system('cp {} {}'.format(orign_name, new_name)) # might need to add full paths here..
```

---

Note that if you only randomly permute the individual numbers and `os.rename` from old to new, you might step on your own files.
For example, suppose you assign id 1 to 20 and 20 to 3, then when you process id 1 you `rename('individual_1_side1.jpg', 'individual_20_side1.jpg')` so by the time you want to change 20 to 3, `'individual_20_side1.jpg'` is no longer of individual 20, but a rename file of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`.

```
import os

from itertools import groupby

filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir("path/2/dir")]

for _, group in groupby(filenames, key=lambda item: item[:-5]):

    for filename in group:

        # genreate random numbner

        # rename old name to new name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to figure out how to pair the files, I would use a dictionary. The keys for the dictionary would be the individual numbers, and the values would be a list of the photos/filenames. Something like this:

```
list_of_filenames = []
pairs = {}
for element in list_of_filenames:
    parts_of_filename = element.split("_")
    unspecific_name = parts_of_filename[0]
    individual_number = parts_of_filename[1]
    type_of_photo = parts_of_filename[2]
    if dict[individual_number]:
        dict[individual_number].append(element)
    else:
        dict[individual_number] = [element]
```

Answer (score 0):

To randomly change the number assigned to each individual:

```
import random
l = ["individual_1_side1.jpg","individual_1_side2.jpg", "individual_98_side1.jpg", "individual_98_side2.jpg"]

numbers = [int(i.split("_")[1]) for i in l]

new_numbers = {}

for i in set(numbers):
   new_val = None
   while True:
       new_val = random.randint(1, 100)
       if new_val != i and new_val not in new_numbers.values():

           break
   new_numbers[i] = new_val

new_files = [i.split("_")[0]+"_"+str(new_numbers[int(i.split("_")[1])])+"_"+i.split("_")[-1] for i in l]

print(new_files)
```

Output:

```
['individual_23_side1.jpg', 'individual_23_side2.jpg', 'individual_42_side1.jpg', 'individual_42_side2.jpg'
```